# Laravel Vue 3 Project when npm run dev: Error: opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I have a laravel 9 vue 3 project.
After php artisan serve when I run npm run dev, I receive following error:

```
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

After checking other stackoverflow posts I added this to my package.json file but no use I guess because its for vue-cli and I need something for npm run dev.

```
 "serve": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service lint"
```

I'm using Node version 18.13

How to resolve this fast? I want to use downgrading as last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, add the following to your package.json:

```
    "dev": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npm run development",
```